# DataGridView Remove Error

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I want to delete the duplicate value and blank lines in the DataGridView.
I am using the following code for this.

```
Private Sub dgwsil()
  On Error Resume Next
  For i2 As Integer = DataGridView1.RowCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
    If Trim(DataGridView1.Rows(i2).Cells(0).Value.ToString()) = "" Then
      DataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(i2)
    End If
  Next

  Dim numberOfRows = DataGridView1.Rows.Count
  Dim i As Integer = 0
  While i < numberOfRows - 2
    For ii As Integer = (numberOfRows - 1) To (i + 1) Step -1
      If DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString() = DataGridView1.Rows(ii).Cells(0).Value.ToString() Then
        DataGridView1.Rows.Remove(DataGridView1.Rows(ii))
        numberOfRows -= 1
      End If
    Next
    i += 1
  End While
End Sub
```

Code sometimes works fine.

[image: like in this photo]

But sometimes it gives an error

[image: like this]

How can I solve this problem ? Or is there any code you use for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Not really enough information given to help, but perhaps one of the cell values is null and you are trying to call `ToString` on it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are going into this problem with a VBA mindset. In VBA, you would usually manipulate the `datagridview` directly and the `On Error Resume Next` line would be acceptable.

In VB.NET you don't want to do either of those things. Your `datagridview` should be bound to a collection of information. That collection can be a `datatable` or an `array` or any type of collection really. So instead of using a loop to manipulate the `datagridview` directly you would either loop through the backing collection or better yet `LINQ` through the collection and manipulate it however you need. There are a ton of tutorials out there explaining everything you could ever need so googling around for how to bind a `datatable` to a `datagridview` should get you what you need.

I would also suggest looking into the `Try...Catch...Finally...` structure. You should really use that to handle any errors that could possibly come up from your code.